# Invalid search Filter in Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I am using `DirectorySearcher` to make an LDAP request in Active Directory, but I keep having an `ArgumentException` thrown because of an invalid filter. Most probably because of a wrong form of `accountExpires` attribute from Active Directory. I would like to find all expired accounts using LDAP, but how can I convert `DateTime.Now` to `accountExpires` format? This is what I've done and it raises an exception. if I take out the accountExpires attribute, it doesn't create any problem :

```
search.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)"+
                   "(!(objectClass=contact))"+
                   "(accountExpires>0)"+
                   "(accountExpires<=129383640000000000)"+
                  ")";
```

I don't really know how to convert dates to `accountExpires` format, and I believe the problem to come from a wrong date format.

Any ideas?

Comment: "I don't really know how to convert dates to accountExpires format": accountExpires is a Windows file time: you can convert to/from DateTime using `DateTime.ToFileTimeUtc` / `DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc`

Comment: Does the `accountExpires` conditions if to filter only account which have an expiracy date ? If it is, does this condition work ? : 
`(!(|(accountExpires=0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)(accountExpires=0)))` (According to http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/AccountExpires )

Comment: @Esteban This works, but it does not get me all the results I need (just one out of 15). But no exception

Comment: @Esteban This gets all accounts that have an expiration date right? Because even filtering with this, I still get users with accountExpires=0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Comment: It should gives you all the account which have an `accountExpires` attribute set AND set with a value which should not be : never expires

Comment: @Esteban Well I changed to accountExpires=9223372036854775807 and with a few conditions added, I get the results I needed! Thanks, put an answer with this and I'll mark as answer ;)

Comment: I edited my answer with these informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter seems to be not compatible with LDAP filter syntax, the negation should be placed on the condition, not as a condition :

`(objectClass!=contact)` should be written : `(!(objectClass=contact))`

It doesn't seem to me that the syntax of the `accountExpires` conditions are wrong, your conditions mean that the account has an expiration date set and should be "syntaxically" valid.

If what you want to achieve is to filter accounts which do have an expiration date and which this date is not "never", you could use this syntax : 
(according to ldapwiki.com/wiki/AccountExpires )

`(!(|(accountExpires=0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)(accountExpires=0)))`

or

`(!(|(accountExpires=9223372036854775807)(accountExpires=0)))`

Answer (score 1):

That must be because of improper way of passing string, try closing double quotes after each line.

```
search.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)"+
                       "(objectClass!=contact)"+
                       "(accountExpires>0)"+
                       "(accountExpires<=129383640000000000)"+
                      ")";
```

Comment: Thanks but I actually have it all on one line, I just did this for clarity :)

Comment: I knew it, it was a long shot.!

Comment: Can you check if accountExpires argument value is correct ?

Comment: Yeah I'm guessing the problem comes from there, gonna investigate :p

Comment: Is it possible to post entire method here? That would be helpful for debugging.

Comment: IU'm pretty sure it comes from there, I just have `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher` objects, and then I read the properties